# What is the color of labels in address book?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicolor

Does any one know the color of labels in the address book? For example when you open a contact you can observe the color of "phone" or "home" labels. 
So what is that color? Do you have any idea?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Prathap.

Answer (score 7):

The standard system colors used by Apple are not documented and you have to figure them out yourself (sadly). However, you find a good list [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php?title=UIColor). In your case I guess it's *tableCellBlueTextColor*. You even can include an [extra header](http://github.com/kennytm/iphone-private-frameworks/blob/master/UIKit/UIColor2.h) with these definitions, but I wouldn't do that for apps submitted to the App Store since it's private framework. You could define it as follows:

```
#define TABLE_CELL_BLUE_TEXT_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:0.22 green:0.33 blue:0.53 alpha:1.0];
```

And then use it in your code:

```
label.textColor = TABLE_CELL_BLUE_TEXT_COLOR
```

Hope it helps.
Raphael

Comment: It is /not/ a Private Framework -- its undocumented methods on a (very) public one!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. However, the way(s) I described are still valid, good to go and helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at "System Colors" section in UIColor class reference. There're class method to get some preset color values, `+lightTextColor` and `+darkTextColor` are likely the ones you are looking for.

Comment: May be I'm not properly conveyed my message to you? I'm just looking about the colors of "mobile" or "IPhone" or "Home" labels in a contact's info view.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple, I need to create a UITableViewCell with with style "UITableViewCellStyleValue2". That's it. Very simple solution.